# Occult fantasy book in which a woman is trying to teach herself witch magic as a way to fight back against her overbearing husband

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, urban-fantasy

Trying to remember a book in the occult genre - modern day magic - in which a woman is trying to teach herself witch magic as a way to fight back against her overbearing, controlling husband. It turns out her husband is deep in the occult. The climactic fight scene takes place in a defunct zoo.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Sworn to the Night* by Craig Schaefer sprang immediately to mind when reading this question.

From the blurb on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/37806236-sworn-to-the-night):

> On the other side of the city, Nessa Roth is a college professor trapped in a loveless marriage, an unwilling prop in a political dynasty. She's also a fledgling witch, weaving poppets and tiny spells behind closed doors.

A bit later on in the blurb:

> Just outside New York, an abandoned zoo becomes the hunting-ground for servants of a savage and alien king.

I recall the ending battle being in the zoo, but I could be recalling it wrong.

Comment: that's the one! thanks DafyddNZ!